# C# Uwp execute a function when a user stops typing in a text box

Tags: c#, windows

I have this textbox

```
<TextBox  Name="truck_reg_no" />
```

When a user finishes typing on the textbox i would like to fire an event

I have tried

```
<TextBox  FocusDisengaged="truck_reg_no_FocusDisengaged"  Name="truck_reg_no"
            />
```

The FocusDisengaged Is never fired

Which event can i add to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

[FocusDisengaged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Control_FocusDisengaged) is for game pad/remote interaction. If you want to get notified when input focus is taken away from the `TextBox`, just use the `LostFocus` event.

For your requirement, you need an event that is fired after user stops typing (for a while), even if the focus is still on the `TextBox`. There is no built-in event for this, instead you can implement this logic by utilizing some kind of timer.

The idea is to start a timer with a set interval (like 1 second) when the user types any key. During this interval, if user types another key, the timer is reset and restart again; If the interval is elapsed, you know user has not type any key in the last 1 second.

Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28346418/815938).