# How to prevent multiple consecutive 'Enter' key press on a button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, key-bindings

I have a button, When I press 'Enter' Key through Keyboard, the button command executes. When I consecutively press the 'Enter' key, the command also executes multiple times which I don't want.

I want to restrict the behaviour to single execution of command even during multiple 'Enter' key press. Can somebody help ?

View.xaml

```
<Button x:Name="btnSearch" IsDefault="True"  Content="Search"  Command="{Binding SearchButtonCommand}">
      <Button.InputBindings>
          <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=SearchButtonCommand}" Key="Return" />
      </Button.InputBindings>
</Button>
```

ViewModel.cs

```
public ICommand SearchButtonCommand
{
 get { return new DelegateCommand(SearchButtonExecutionLogic); }
}
```

Comment: For this Problem I added a timer, and when enter is send I block sending enter again for, let's say, 2 seconds

Comment: many ways you can do that. may be a timer , or removing the click event from the button after first click , or making the button as non clickable after first click, or you can you Jquery .one(), or just have a global flag and make it's value false after first click and you can write a condition check after click   etc..

Comment: [Related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001450/c-sharp-wait-for-user-to-finish-typing-in-a-text-box)

Comment: how about change focus after key entered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to reach your goal is to introduce and check some flag `isSearchRunning` in your command implementation in ViewModel:

```
private bool isSearchRunning = false;
private void SearchButtonCommandImpl()
{
    if (isSearchRunning)
    {
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        isSearchRunning = true;
        //Do stuff
    }
    finally
    {
        isSearchRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do this, it's a good idea to provide the user with some feedback when the flag is set. You could disable the button, or change it's caption to 'running', or display a messagebox when the button is clicked a second time.

Comment: @RobinBennett Yes, there are many possibilities how a state of ViewModel (namely `IsSearchRunning`) can be represented in the View.