# Textbox validation when lower than the desired number

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

In my textbox, the value accepted should be in range of 80 - 160. There are no problems when the user inputs number greater than 160. But for the 80, when the user starts typing, it automatically changes to 80 since a 1-digit integer is lower than 80. What approach should I take here?

```
private void tbox_Power_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    if (tb.Text != String.Empty && int.Parse(tb.Text) > 160)
        tb.Text = "160";
    else if (tb.Text != String.Empty && int.Parse(tb.Text) < 80)
        tb.Text = "80";
    else if (tb.Text == String.Empty)
        tb.Text = "0";
}
```

Comment: You could use the LostFocus event.

Comment: [might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001450/c-sharp-wait-for-user-to-finish-typing-in-a-text-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I can think of is to allow the user to type the desired number then, after a short while (let's say, 5 seconds) to do the desired processing. You can use a `Timer` instance, set the delay to 5000 and set it on as a `LostFocus` event handler. In the `Timer`'s `Tick` event you can do whatever processing you want.

Comment: I did this and it worked. I delayed the process for validation 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a [`NumericUpDown` control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/numericupdown-control-windows-forms) for getting numeric input from the user. You can set the `Minimum` and `Maximum` values, and don't have to do any parsing.

Comment: That is a great suggestion. Will try that. Thanks.